# Using Delphi XE5 can I present a modal dialog with an animation like PresentModal... in Xcode

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am looking to launch a Form/View in delphi that results in the same experience as using:

Pretty Animation:

```
[self presentViewController:signInController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

No Animation:

```
SignInForm.ShowModal(procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
begin
  if ModalResult = mrOK then
  begin
    ShowMessage('test');
  end;
end);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an approved best practice for this. In the end I had to create an animation and display it with that manual animation :(